# How do I make PHP emulate whatever PostgreSQL's to_timestamp() function does?

Tags: php, postgresql

Peruse this common SQL pattern found in my code:

```
INSERT INTO table
(
    col1,
    col2,
    col3,
    col4, -- This column is a timestamptz.
    col5,
    col6
)
VALUES
(
    $1,
    $2,
    $3,
    to_timestamp($4), -- I'm trying to make this into $4.
    $5,
    $6
)
```

The $4 value is sent a Unix timestamp from PHP.

PostgreSQL doesn't (for whatever reason) understand PHP's Unix epoch timestamps directly, but must have that to_timestamp() call around the Unix timestamp in order to not error out when the query is run.

I want to once and for all move the responsibility for turning this into a natively PG-accepted timestamptz value, so that I can eliminate the to_timestamp() in the SQL query.

This means that I need to turn my $Unix_timestamp PHP variable into $PG_accepting_timestamp. But what exactly is that?

I've been digging around the PG manual for many hours before asking you. I hope you can tell me exactly what format it wants, and how to best convert it in a non-ugly, robust manner.

Answer (score 0):

[`to_timestamp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-datetime.html) converts a unix timestamp into a date/time string, so using PHP to generate an equivalent string should solve your problem. For example,

```
$d = date_create_from_format('U', 1195374767);
echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```